# Making sense of a book page "Advanced Calculus" by Wrede and Spiegel

Tags: calculus

I'm skimming through the book "Advanced Calculus, Third Edition" by Wrede and Spiegel.
I can't make sense of book page 107:
https://i.postimg.cc/85H3dbWJ/IMG_0120a.jpg

What does the symbol "epsilon" mean which I marked in red boxes?

Help would be much appreciated!

Comment: Is there an index of symbols in the book?  I suspect it means $\ge$.  There may be a typo , also, I think.

Comment: I looked it up and it was $\ge$.  Plus there was a typo:  should be $g(x)\ge f(x)$ on $[a,b]$.  Not sure what happened in your version.

Comment: Okay, thanks! With $\geq$ it would make sense.
There is no index of symbols in the book.
As stated: it's the third edition I have borrowed from the library.
Which edition do you have?

Comment: The second edition...